# Increase wake lock time span till my service is running in background in android

Tags: android, service, wakelock

My application is running a service . What i want is that , I want screen to awake till my service running in background. I have used this

```
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"x2_wakelook");
wakeLock.acquire();
wakeLock.release();
```

But this code does not work till life span of my service. Screen goes to sleep as soon as i get out of my application. Any help !

Answer (score 0):

> But this code does not work till life span of my service.

You specifically are releasing the `WakeLock` immediately after acquiring it. You need to move the `release()` call to the point where you want the `WakeLock` to be released.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I put whole code here that i am using. I know that where i have to release lock at end of my service.